# One of my GitHub repositories is missing several commits. How can I tell if another user force pushed, and if so, how to fix it?

Tags: git, github, git-push

So some of my users are missing several commits to a commonly used remote repo. It looks like someone may have been doing force push and orphaning commits but I don't yet know who (we have some suspicions).

When I cloned the repo and tried to create a branch off the SHA for one of the missing commits, (thinking I could merge it back in) I got errors telling me that the SHA was not a commit. I figure that's because my clone didn't have that part of the history to recognize it. GitHub does allow me to examine that commit when I pop it directly into the URL, but it doesn't appear accessible any other way. I tried:  `$git log --walk-reflogs` but it doesn't show the missing commits. Reflog doesn't show any of them either, and only shows my own changes (a branch off of our dev branch to use as a staging for fixing this issue isolated from the regular branch) . Again, probably I'll have to have the users do that themselves and show me the output.

My other users still have their changes in their locals. I could ask them to push everything again and make sure that no one is using force push.

**How can I find out what actually happened and fix it?**

Comment: Reflogs are local to each Git: a new clone has no reflogs. You'd want to find an old clone that had the commits at some point, and still has its reflogs from that point, to get these. You *might* be able to get the commits back from some of the GitHub semi-secret refs (the `refs/pull/*` space), which will let you get them locally and then resurrect them easily. To find out, use `git ls-remote` to see what's really there on GitHub.

Comment: I'll take a look. The developers all still have their local repos with their changes and can just re-submit I guess. Might be easier than trying to have them dig commits out of their own histories. Thanks!

Comment: Would I be able to use clone --mirror to get the full history and restore the commit from there?

Comment: Using `git clone --mirror` just tells your own Git to use all the refs (not reflogs, just refs) that the other Git has. If the `refs/pull/*` refs give you access to the commits you want, that's one way to get the `refs/pull/*` refs, but you could also just run `git fetch origin 'refs/pull/*:refs/pull/*'`.